# Extend disk for Ubuntu using gparted

Tags: partitioning, parted

- I am running a dual boot system with Ubuntu and Windows.
- I initially gave Ubuntu 50GB.
- I would like to add an additional 80GB.
- In windows I shrunk the existint NTFS partition to give me 80G for ubuntu. In ubuntu I created the ext4 partition.
  However, I would like to extend the current partition running ubuntu to use this new 80GB. -The issue is that I cannot move the current partition *before* the 80GB and so I cannot extend it. How can this be done? I cannot move or resize the current Ubuntu partition...
- As you can see from the image, I want to extend nvme0n1p5 to use 1p6.

[image: the last partition is the current ubuntu partition. How to extend it with the partition before it?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you do any of it, make sure you have a drive backup!

You should be able to proceed using the following steps:

- shrink the nmve0n1p4 (I think you already did that)
- you should gain some unused space
- if you have created nmve0n1p6 out of that unused space, remove that empty partition. We need to extend the existing partition with free space, not a partition merge
- once the p6 is removed, you should be able to extend the p5 with this empty space you have just gained

If the above is not possible in your case, using Resize/move (still, with no "empty" partitions ), you should be able to move the ubuntu partition to the left, and once this part is done, extend it with free space that will be now behind it. Just keep in mind the "move" operation takes some time, probably a good idea to leave it overnight.

Comment: Yes I've tried this. However after unallocating p6 I cannot move or resize p5. I think this is because I am logged in?

Comment: yes, you need to run partition operations off a USB ubuntu drive, you cannot change the disk you're currently running operating system from